# Django REST framework - endpoint for username

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, endpoint

In my application users names can contain chars like :

```
. @ - _
```

I want to make an API endpoint api/users/{username} but it's impossible with these chars in URL. How to bite this kind of problem?

Comment: What else can the username contain? Digits? Does it always start with a letter?

Comment: letters a-zA-Z and digits and must start with a letter

Answer (score 2):

You need to use URL encoding for that and decode it in your view.

So `"Username. @ - _"` will be encoded as `"Username.+%40+-+_"`.

To decode you can use `urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')`.